# Tizen package manger not recognizing JDK

Tags: java, windows, sdk, installation, tizen

First and foremost I am very novice to this so I may not understand all technical terms or how to do everything but will try to and ask followup questions if I have. I've been trying to install TiZen studio, which worked fine until I tried to open the package manager. I can open Tizen Studio, but cannot open the package manager. I've tried to redownload latest jdks etc and read that it may also be due to wrongly implemented environment variables, so I tried to set them but nothing works. [Error message when trying to open package-manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiEVD.png)

My systemvariables looks like these;[these are my PATH variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDnKF.png). Am I doing something obvious wrong? I am sorry for the inconvenience, and what environment variables should I set, where and how?

Computer runs on windows 10!

UPDATE: Can't open Tizen studio anymore. Might've happened sometime after I've changed those environtment variables or something. Not sure, and can't make out what the log means. This is the [log](https://justpaste.it/4ynqm) I got from the last attempted startup. I know it's tons of text, but I have no idea what it means or what to look for, and maybe someone knows what to do or what anything means.

Thanks in advance!
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60898958/tyzen-studio-package-manager-does-not-open-with-java-nullpointer-execption-and) that later I updated with solution.

For your issues, here's probable solution that might help you. 
You need to set JAVA_HOME variable with value of correct version of JDK that Tizen studio supports. [This Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/download/prerequisites) states the requirements.

Let me know if it helped you.