# Tyzen studio package manager does not open with java nullpointer execption. and many tools can not open

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

I am having lots of issues with windows version of Tizen studio such as emulator manager, control panel doesn't open. So I tried mac version but installing it on startup it could not open package manager with  "Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NullPointerException) cause: null" error, despite having valid JDK 11 and latest installer 3.6. No valid [solution](https://developer.tizen.org/forums/sdk-ide/tizen-studio-doesnt-work-on-mac-catalina) found so far. So should we abandon Tizen studio for lack of support and improvements? Does any one has solution?

**EDIT - Solution:**

I was able to run required tools such as Emulator manager after I used JDK8 on Windows and I didn't test but this should work with mac too. I wish there was more information about it on the first time. Using other updated version of JDK doesn't give any error but it requires JDK12 or JDK8 as stated [here](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/download/prerequisites).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a [newer version Tizen Studio](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/download) available.

Version 3.7 is bundled with Java and does not need any Java related setting in the system, thus avoiding all the issues stated above.

Comment: Here is the link to the release notes: https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/download/release-notes